# Is it possible to have more "levels" of draft/published statuses?

Tags: post-status

Is there any way to have more post statuses other than just draft or published?

For example, if you write a lot of posts, you may wish to type up all the content, and set the status of these posts as "Content - Drafted"

Then you can re-style them, make text bold, add code highlighting etc, and set to "Styled - Drafted"

Then as a final review you could set status to "Reviewed"

Then finally, publish them

Is it possible in the current wordpress version 3 to achieve such scenarios?

Comment: The status values for posts are pluggable ... but I don't know of any plugins currently on the market that allow you to create custom post status(es) like this ... but yes, it is possible to achieve such scenarios.  Now here's my follow-up: are you looking for a plugin or drop-in code for your `functions.php` file to do this?  Are you comfortable manipulating code, or would you want someone else to put things together for you?

Comment: *@EAMann* - Unless I'm having a memory failure statuses are not completely pluggable in v3.0.1 yet, but there is a plan to fix that for v3.1. The Publish metabox hardcodes its statuses so even if you register new statuses there is not a hook to add to the Publish metabox. Of course you could make it work with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` but that's hackish and fragile (though it does work!)

Comment: *@James Elsey* - Nice question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this plugin [called EditFlow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/) that says it allows you to add custom statuses. Apparently it's designed for use in a newsroom. (FYI, I searched the WordPress plugins directory for "custom post status.")

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is via tags - or cateogry - requires no additional plugin and somehow works

good question tho, helps in collaborating

Comment: The problem with tags or categories is that they are semantic taxonomies, e.g., they describe the content itself. They're not the greatest solution in the world for this, since their intent is for external use. They do work though, because they're labels and that's what is needed. Just not ideal.

Comment: when post in edit mode - it is not published yet - so u can have brainstorm as a tag - then edit1 as another tag and such - those tags will never be published - the last last editor will remove them and publish - so it can come down to a convention